# Lua script attempting to call nil

Tags: c++, lua

I have a simple Lua function which I have taken and modified from an online source that modifies a specific line in another Lua file. The function seems to be attempting to call a nil value as `PANIC: unprotected error in call to Lua API (attempt to call a nil value)` pops up on my console. This function is being called by another C++ function. I have practically zero experience with Lua and have no idea what is going on.

The script:

```lua
function ModLine(value, line)
    print("Modding...")
    local file = io.open("Image/DM2240_HighScore.lua", "r")
    sContents = file:read() -- capture file in a string
    file:close()
    tContents = textutils.unserialize(sContents) -- convert string to table

    --Print a specific line
    print(tContents[line])

    --Modify a specific line
    table.remove(tContents, line) -- will remove line so we can insert the new line 
    table.insert(tContents, line, value) -- inserts value on line in the table.

    --Convert table to string and save the file
    sContents = textutils.serialize(tContents)
    file = io.open("Image/DM2240_HighScore.lua", "w")
    file:write(sContents)
    file:close()
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I checked some functions and found out that the problem lies within this function,

```
void LuaInterface::ModLine(const int value, const int line) {
    cout << "Modded" << endl;
    lua_getglobal(theLuaState, "ModLine");
    lua_pushinteger(theLuaState, value);
    lua_pushinteger(theLuaState, line);
    lua_call(theLuaState, 2, 0);
}
```

Comment: It seems you read the whole file contents into one string variable, but actually `file:read()` only reads the first line. To read the whole file: `file:read(*all)`. If `line` is higher than 1, the function might not work as expected.

Comment: @DiegoPino after changing that, it goes past the `print("Modding...")` line this time, but it still produces the same error

Comment: What I would do is to test the Lua function alone to be 100% sure it works as expected, possibly passing different value and lines values. This error you got "attempt to call a nil value" is usually due to calling an object function with a colon instead of a semicolon. If seems `textutils` is a  custom object defined somewhere else. Is it the call to `unserialize` correct? Depending on how is defined the call could be `textutils:unserialize()`...

Comment: Is the script with *ModLine* executed correctly?